# Pandas DF stacked filters not working, getting error on range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to filter based on both date range and columns, then present graphs of the data. Unfortunately I'm getting an error when I do.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

ticker = yf.Ticker("mnf.ax")
history = ticker.history(period="max").reset_index()
history["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(history["Date"])
history = history.set_index('Date')

# this works
history['2019-01-01' : '2020-07-01'].resample('W').mean().plot.line(figsize=(20, 16), subplots=True)

# This also works
history[['Low','High']].resample('W').mean().plot.line(figsize=(20, 16), subplots=True)

# However this doesn't
history[['2019-01-01' : '2020-07-01'],['Low','High]]'.resample('W').mean().plot.line(figsize=(20, 16), subplots=True)
```

Would love some insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be incorrectly using the brackets. I suggest you use `loc` for this case:

```
history.loc['2019-01-01':'2020-07-01'][['Low','High']].resample('W').mean().plot.line(figsize=(20, 16), subplots=True)
```

Disaggregating:

```
history.loc['2019-01-01':'2020-07-01'] #Returns the full dataframe within the specified dates

[['Low','High']] # Selects the specific columns

.resample('W').mean().plot.line(figsize=(20, 16), subplots=True) ## Resamples, aggregates using mean and plots.
```

Comment: Great, thanks that works, still need to get my head around the use of brackets in these instances

Comment: Glad to be of help, feel free to accept my answer if it helped you solve the problem. Here is a lot of useful information and example regarding this topic! https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html